# how to do incremental indexing in Lucene.Net?

Tags: wpf, lucene.net

how to do incremental indexing in Lucene.Net ?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the documents that are updated and re-add them as new documents

Comment: i have not given a particular id to document i want to search document by query....

Comment: how can i delete the particular documents?

Comment: You need to use an indexReader to go to the document and then use Delete. You need to either use an id to find it or iterate through all the documents until you get to the one you want.

Comment: through iterating it will take too much time.......bcos that collection is very large..                            do u have Any another option...

Comment: Yes, put an id in each document and search by id